# I have a customer transaction database. I need to select the 3rd successful payment in the data and show the date of that payment. Using T-sql

Tags: sql-server

In the data below, these first payment is pro-rata payment and I will ignore that one. Transaction 4 is a reversal of transaction 3.  So the 3rd successful transaction is transaction number 5.

In my data the reversal might not always be in the same month and it might not always be the same amount.

| transNumber | TransType | Date | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EFT | 2021-09-19 | -700.00 |
| 2 | EFT | 2021-10-01 | -1000.00 |
| 3 | EFT | 2021-11-01 | -1000.00 |
| 4 | EFTREVA | 2021-11-05 | 1000.00 |
| 5 | EFT | 2021-12-01 | -1000.00 |
| 6 | EFT | 2022-01-01 | -1000.00 |

Comment: How do you know that transNumber 4 is a reversal of 3? You said they may not always be in the same month nor even the same amount so how do you know it's a reversal for 3 and not a reversal for 2? Is there something else like a "reference" column that links reversals to the original transaction?

Comment: Hi there, The transaction type advises me it is a reversal.  EFT is successful payment and  EFTREVA is a reversal of a EFT.   It is because of the trend that the data follows that I am taking that transaction number 3 was reversed.   Unfortunately there is not reference in my table that advises me which transactions was reversed.  So somebody might reverse the amount and forget to take into consideration the vat, for example and it is this instance where the amount might differ.

Comment: Well that's problematic. If you were asked to return the second successful payment instead of the third successful payment then which is the correct answer, 2 or 3? You're only guessing that the reversal applies to 3, but it may actually apply to 2. Which transaction you apply reversals to affects the outcome.

Comment: Typically you use ROW_NUMBER to find the "nth" row. As already mentioned, the logic you need to partition and order your rows is not obvious. IME one typically sees a direct relationship between a reversing transaction and the original transaction. Your table lacks - perhaps lag/lead might work (which involves a major assumption and associated risk).

Comment: Thank you for replying guys.  I did not think of lag/lead.  Will see if that works.